# JavaFX performance issues with ImagePattern on canvas

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a 2D game with a hexagon grid as map in JavaFX.

I use a `Canvas` to draw custom `Hexagon` objects via `fillPolygon()` and now want to fill those hexagons with `ImagePattern` objects included in the project as .png files sized 100x100px.

While trying to put the game in a render loop using `AnimationTimer` I came across some performance issues.

Drawing the map using `ImagePattern` only gives me 10-20 FPS while using a `Color` as fill gives me quite stable 60 FPS. The `ImagePattern` are loaded from a `HashMap<TerrainType, ImagePattern>` which is constructed at the start of the application.

The main part of the drawing methods looks like this:

```
boardGraphicsContext.setFill(
    resourceMap.getTerrainSprite(gameBoardNodes[i][j].getTerrainType())
);

boardGraphicsContext.fillPolygon(
    Hexagon.polygonCornersX(layout, hex), 
    Hexagon.polygonCornersY(layout, hex), 
    6
);
```

I also tried to set the fill before entering the loop and don't change it at all, which didn't improve the performance either.

The map consists of 20x20 hexagons.

In case it matters: I'm using a MacBook Pro from 2017 with some dual core i5 and Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640 with 1536MB of memory.

Is there a possibility to improve the performance using the canvas approach?

Greetings

**Update:**

The actual problem here is now that using a .png as texture for the hexagons scrolling with my MacBooks trackpad seems quite sluggish, while using a plain color instead is way smoother. I can't tell if this is a limitation of my computer, JavaFX or my specific implementation.

In my initial post I stated that I'm using a Canvas for drawing the game, but the following scene graph implementation has the same problem as the Canvas implementation, but is way more compact and suitable for posting.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.ImagePattern;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        AnchorPane boardPane = new AnchorPane();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                HexNode newNode = new HexNode(i, j, "GRASS");
                boardPane.getChildren().add(newNode);
            }
        }

        boardPane.setOnScroll(scrollEvent -> {
            double deltaY = scrollEvent.getDeltaY();
            double zoomFactor = 1.05;

            if (deltaY < 0){
                zoomFactor = 2.0 - zoomFactor;
            }

            boardPane.setScaleX(boardPane.getScaleX() * zoomFactor);
            boardPane.setScaleY(boardPane.getScaleY() * zoomFactor);
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(boardPane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class HexNode extends Polygon {
    private final String type;
    private final ResourceMap resourceMap = ResourceMap.getInstance();

    public HexNode(int x, int y, String type) {
        super();
        double height = 50;
        this.type = type;

        double r = height / 2.0;
        double h = r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(30));
        double w = r * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(30));

        double xOffset, yOffset;
        if (y % 2 == 0) {
            xOffset = 2 * w * x;
        } else {
            xOffset = 2 * w * x + w;
        }
        yOffset = 2 * r * y - (y * h);

        this.getPoints().addAll(
                w + xOffset, 0.0 + yOffset,
                2 * w + xOffset, h + yOffset,
                2 * w + xOffset, 2 * r - h + yOffset,
                w + xOffset, 2 * r + yOffset,
                0.0 + xOffset, 2 * r - h + yOffset,
                0.0 + xOffset, h + yOffset
        );

        drawType();
    }

    private void drawType() {
        this.setFill(new ImagePattern(resourceMap.getTerrainSprite(type)));
        // this.setFill(Color.BLACK); is much better
    }
}

class ResourceMap {

    private static final ResourceMap instance = new ResourceMap();
    private final HashMap<String, Image> terrainSprites = new HashMap<>();

    private ResourceMap() {
        terrainSprites.put("GRASS", loadSpriteFromPath("PATH_TO_PNG"));
    }

    public static ResourceMap getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public Image getTerrainSprite(String terrainType) {
        return terrainSprites.get(terrainType);
    }

    private Image loadSpriteFromPath(String filePath) {
        return new Image(filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 0):

To my opinion you are using a completely wrong approach for that purpose. Instead of a Canvas you should use the scene graph for that. You could then just put some ImageViews in a grid and move that arround as you like without any performance hits. I do such stuff on a regular basis. Just have a look here for example: https://twitter.com/MichaelPaus/status/1272197273313738752/photo/1

Comment: I implemented a version using the scene graph and Polygon objects and got quite similar results. If I use a simple Color as fill for the Polygons, performance while zooming is quite good. If I use ImagePattern the performance drops to the level of the Canvas/ImagePattern implementation.

Comment: That's strange but what is going wrong here could only be answered by having more insight into your actual code.

Comment: I updated my initial post with some more code.

Comment: But the new code you showed is probably irrelevant to your problem. You have a performance problem but you only show one-time initialization code which obviously worked because otherwise you would not only complain about performance. The real question is how you use that code in each animation step?

Comment: There are no actual animations in the game, it's a static board game and the requirement is zooming and panning the game board, and the zooming part is where I got the issue. I added a minimal example of the problem instead of my initialization code.

Comment: Could you make a zip-file with all your code and all resources available somewhere? I'd be interested to have a look into this. It might be that there is indeed a performance problem with JavaFX here.